# Print to PDF from Firefox and Chromium text is image not selectable

Tags: firefox, chromium, pdf, text

I have recently upgraded from 10.04 LTS to 12.04 LTS (fully up-to-date). Complete fresh format and install of the Linux partition.

I noticed that PDF files printed from Firefox 14.0.1 and Chromium 18.0.1025.168 (Developer Build 134367 Linux) sometimes do not contain selectable text. However, initially, I didn't realize it was in some way dependent upon the web page being printed.

After some time, I discovered that printing only some web pages result in un-selectable text [text is image only], in both Firefox and Chromium. For [example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molybdenum). However, printing some pages result in selectable text, for [example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicycle).

So far as I can tell, the problem seems to affect both Firefox and Chromium equally, although I have only tested on several web pages, including the BBC. So far, I have not found a page which affected one browser and not the other.

Initially I thought it might be a damaged CUPS-PDF (because this had always worked before in previous Ubuntu versions), but I removed and reinstalled that. I also removed and reinstalled Firefox. I believe it doesn't appear to be postscript, although I don't really understand the details of how pages are constructed for printing – (I removed and reinstalled GV). Restarts made no difference.
I found that printing to PDF from LibreOffice isn't apparently affected.

So, I'm beginning to suspect that it's most probably in Linux, or in both browsers – but that seems rather less likely, but it could be something else that affects both browsers.

I have to say that I'm stumped. Please help!

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Comment: Any outcome over the years what was at fault?

Comment: @RobertSiemer it looks like this won't be fixed [discussion on bugs.debian.org](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=658004). It's a pity.
I suggest you use the built-in "pint to file" instead, although it is less user friendly.